# Working with multiple discontinuous selection

Tags: vba, ms-word, multipleselection

I'm trying to do something with a multiple selection. I wanna add some text before every selected paragraph but, when I select multiple discontinuous paragraphs, if I do Selection.Paragraphs.Count I always get "1".

How could I work with all paragraphs apart?

Example:

```
Paragraph1(Selected first)
Paragraph2
Paragraph3(Selected second)
```

What I got when I try to add some text at the beginning of these paragraphs:

```
Paragraph1
Paragraph2
TEXTParagraph3
```

What I really want to obtain:

```
TEXTParagraph1
Paragraph2
TEXTParagraph3
```

I'm working like this:

```
sub x()
  dim p as paragraph
  for each p in selection.paragraphs
    p.range.insertbefore("TEXT")
  next
End sub
```

Comment: Dude...the last sentence you have edited...is an error to be polite? XDDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word simply cannot do what you'd like for it to do. Developers have wished for this since multiple selections were introduced in 2003 (I think it was, might have been version 2007). Word's object model simply does not support it.

If this is something you want to provide to the user to make life easier you'll need to give the tool a way to mark the paragraphs so your code can recognize them. You could provide a macro, for example, that assigns an incrementing bookmark name to each selection (the user selects, then runs your macro; repeat for each paragraph). Your code can then address each bookmark and perform the actions. To make this more user friendly you can assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut and/or a button in the Ribbon/QAT and/or the right-click menu.