# Select non-contiguous cells in Word table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using the keyboard & mouse I am able to select multiple non-contiguous cells in a table and change properties such as font size & color and cell shading. I can also select multiple columns (contiguous, have not tried non-contiguous). I cannot find a way to do it in VBA and record macro captures nothing.

My objective is simply to shade cell(1,1) through cell(x,y) one color and cells after that another color. I can't get Word ranges to work for me because they apparently go first by row then by column.

I have a 4 column X 20 row table (for printing labels).  If the 1st 2 cols and half of col 3 have been printed, I would like to denote that by having those cells in the table one shade and the bottom half (rows 11-20) of column 3 and all of col 4 a different shade. I currently accomplish it by looping through all cells in the table and using row & col indices with If THEN ELSE, but there must be a more efficient way.

I know it would be easier if I would use rows first then columns (and that's what I'm doing now), but it irritates me that I can't do something in VBA that I can do manually.

The real situation is slightly more complex in that there can be 2 different label types on the sheet with different text and different pictures. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730750/vba-ms-word-work-with-mutiple-discontinuous-selection

Answer (score 1):

0) don't use rows, use absolute cell ranges

1) if you have 3 sections, you should select them and then recolor them separately

2) the following is a snippet from one of my macros which I use to select only cells 11-17 of all rows past 3 in the 1st table in the document

```
    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1) _
    .Cell(3, 11).Range.Start, End:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1) _  
    .Cell(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count, 17).Range.End).Select
```

3)the following would set the color to a solid light blue
4)I also recommend wdColorAutomatic to make sure text will be visible on a new background

```
    Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
    Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorLightTurquoise
```

5) remember to select your table properly, if you select the table first you can use

```
    set aTable as selection.tables(1)
```

6) to make sure you are in the right table