# Find highlighted ranges after Find.HitHighlight

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto

Is it possible to find the ranges which were highlighted by `Find.HitHighlight` method? Is there any property in the `Range` object I could rely on in order to identify it?

**UPDATE 1**

I want to highlight some words in a document and when user selects a word I want to identify whether selected range was highlighted or not. I'm currently using the `Find.HitHighlight` method but it doesn't allow me to iterate thru the find results and store range positions in the memory so that later I could use this information to identify whether user's selection is highlighted or not. One of the approach is to use `Find.Execute` method to get find results first and then call `Find.HitHighlight` method for those ranges in order to highlight them. The problem with this approach is that now it takes from Word about 1-2 seconds to highlight about 30 words in the loop and Word becomes unresponsive. If I add another call to `Find.Execute` it will take up to 4-5 seconds to highlight words and remember their positions. What I'm looking for is the way how can I see if a selected range was highlighted by `Find.HitHighlight` method. Is there any property in the `Range` object which Word sets when range is temporarily highlighted?

**UPDATE 2**

I don't see any connections between my question and the suggested question about working with multiple selections.

Comment: In a quick search I came across this sentence, "You can use the Find object's Found property to iterate through several found items". That's where you might start your quest for a solution.

Comment: @Variatus thank you for response. I would like to avoid another interop call because performance is very important to me. I know that I can implement it by utilizing `Find.Execute` and highlight the results by calling `Find.HitHighlight` after that but this makes this part of the code slower. I need the way to figure if the selected range is highlighted and identify boundaries of that highlight.

Comment: This request come up regularly, for example: [VBA MS-Word Work with mutiple discontinuous selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730750/vba-ms-word-work-with-mutiple-discontinuous-selection)

Comment: @CindyMeister can you add a bit more details here? I don't understand how multiple selections relate to my question?

Comment: Ummm. You need to edit the information in the exchange with Variatus into the question. And explain *exactly* what you're trying to do. My response would be no different from that comment, based on what's in the question and your reaction to the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have added more details to my question. Hopefully this will help to clarify what I'm looking for.